# Start MongoDB with git bash

Tags: bash, mongodb

```
kevin@KEVIN-PC MINGW64 /C/MongoDB/bin
$ ls
bsondump.exe*  mongodump.exe*    mongoperf.exe*     mongotop.exe*
libeay32.dll*  mongoexport.exe*  mongorestore.exe*  ssleay32.dll*
mongo.exe*     mongofiles.exe*   mongos.exe*
mongod.exe*    mongoimport.exe*  mongos.pdb
mongod.pdb     mongooplog.exe*   mongostat.exe*

kevin@KEVIN-PC MINGW64 /C/MongoDB/bin
$ mongod.exe
bash: mongod.exe: command not found
```

I installed the mongoDB with version Windows 64-bit 2008 R2+ on my windows8.1. Could anyone tell me why I got command not found error when start the mongod.exe?

Comment: You need `./` to run a command from the current directory so use `./mongod.exe`.

Comment: it works, thanks sooooooo much

Answer (score 3):

try ./mongod to run the executable to begin the server then open a second window/terminal. navigate to the same location as your server, then run ./mongo. Should be set!

Answer (score 1):

cd to you installation folder `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin` then `start mongodb server ./mongod`.